# React not getting query params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a strange problem. When I want to go to a link, entered in my browser, in my React app, the query params are not loaded. I will then be immediately redirected to the main link. example:

```
https://localhost:3000/home?query_params_1=1&?query_params_2=2
```

goes to

```
https://localhost:3000/home
```

after load. The params totally deleted after load page.

I've really tried everything. Parts removed... My idea is that the router may be stupid, but so far no results.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard websitedata={websites} />} />
  <Route path='sites/new' element={<AddSite />} />
  <Route path='sites/single/:id/*' element={<SingleSite websitedata={websites} />} />
  <Route path='sites/*' element={<Sites websites={websites} userData={userData} backups={backups} />} />
  <Route path='clients/*' element={<Clients />} />
  <Route path='tickets' element={<Tickets ticketsdata={tickets} />} />
  <Route path='tickets/create' element={<CreateTicket />} />
  <Route path='tickets/:id/*' element={<Ticket />} />
  <Route path='profile/*' element={<Profile data={profileData} />} />
  <Route path='subscription/*' element={<Subscription />} />
  <Route path='manual/*' element={<Manual />} />
  <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

The strange thing is that linking via Router Dom Link does work.

example:

```
<Link to='?page=signup'>Sign up now</Link>
```

Goes to:

```
https://localhost:3000?page=signup
```

Is there anyone with the same kind of problem? Can someone help me look in the right direction? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see any route rendering on `"/home"`. Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve]? Can you also try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @Drew Reese Thanks for your comment. Problem has since been solved due to a stupid bug in the code.

Comment: I see, so similar mistake as Frosty619.

Comment: Yes, After a lot of searching I came across that topic. And also found out that there was an error in the code. I hope that when others have this error, they will benefit from my answer. The solution lies in the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was in the code at the top of the app. I applied a "navigate" with a "pathname" that determines the location. This means that the "query params" are not loaded.